# probleme with modal in controller

Tags: laravel, controller, modal-dialog

I have this line in the controller in search function

```
 <a href="#custom-edit-modal-'.$Arret->id.'" class="table-action-btn" data-animation="fadein" data-plugin="custommodal" data-overlaySpeed="200" data-overlayColor="#36404a">
     <i class="md md-edit"></i>
 </a>
```

I want to passe the `id` and `modal` but in the route it pass and didn't open the modal 
By the way the modal open in other case without search

Comment: Format your code and display better what the problem is.

Comment: Format according to @mentallurg's suggestion first, then fixing typo next.

Comment: how can i put picture?

Comment: Don't put your code as a picture. Put the code a TEXT and format it.

Comment: i want to open the modal not from a html page but from controller
<a href="#custom-edit-modal-'.$Arret->id.'"  this line is where is the probleme 
in the route it show the custom-edit-modal and the id of ARRET but the modal not opend